# javascript string replace function with regex where I can insert a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$(this).html(html.replace(/"expedita"/gi, '<strong>$&</strong>'));
```

which is working but the string to replace is hardcoded, I need to be able to insert a variable

```
$(this).html(html.replace(/"+search+"/gi, '<strong>$&</strong>'));
```

search is a variable I have assigned a value I want to replace, but this code is not working, it seems i can't insert a variable into regex expression.

How can I use regex but not have a hardcoded word and be able to use any word?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)

Comment: Try `$(this).html(html.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), '<strong>$&</strong>'))`.

Comment: @maxit Maybe I should make a full answer, in case of other users have the same problem as you? What do you think?

Comment: Do not answer duplicates, mark/flag them as duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve a flexible and dynamic way to change the replaced expression, use `RegExp` object.

> `$(this).html(html.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), '<strong>$&</strong>'))`

where the `search` is a variable holding the expression you want to replace.